# Is it possible to ensure that a controller is disposed in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, controller, static-analysis

I have several controllers in my code (eg. TextEditingControllers, StreamControllers, ScrollControllers). Is there a way to get a warning/error if I ever forget to call the dispose() method on this variables?

I was hoping that there could be a lint for pedantic, but I couldn't find anything.

To clarify:

If initialize a controller

```
TextEditingController searchFieldController = TextEditingController();
```

And then forget to call

```
 @override
  void dispose() {
    searchFieldController.dispose();  // This line
    super.dispose();
 }
```

It should generate a warning

Comment: Like a runtime or compile time warning?

Comment: If you are using VSCode maybe you can write a cool extension for that kind of warnings.

Comment: Compile time. And I am using Android Studio